# Horizontal scrollbar appears while animations running

Tags: html, css, css-animations

In the mobile resolutions there appears a horizontal scrollbar when i scroll above divs
with animations that adds blank space along the conent of my website.
CSS:

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    position: relative;

  }

html {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color:#060606;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and the CSS Animations:

```css
@keyframes slide-right-opacity {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(200%);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }}
    
@keyframes slide-right {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(100%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity: 2;
    }}
@keyframes slide-out-right {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity: 2;
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(400%);
      opacity: 0;
    }}
@keyframes slide-left {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(-200%);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }}
```

If i remove all the animations, the problem is solved.

Comment: If your elements animate outside of the window, scrollbars may appear. You can fix it using `overflow:hidden` on the container of the elements. Then you simply won't see the elements when they animate outside of the screen.